# How to call a method with a parameter to a toString method in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing code to simulate a deck of cards. I have one method that takes an int and pulls a suit from an array corresponding to a suit and another method for the value of a card. I am having trouble calling those methods at the proper index for a toString method that will take the parameters a user chooses and print out something like: Ace of Spades.The class name is Card. Here is my code:

```
public void setSuit(int num){
          String[] suits = {"clubs", "hearts", "diamonds", "spades"};
          String suit = Integer.toString(num);
          suit = suits[num];
      }
      public void setValue(int num){
          String[] value = {null, "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "King", "Queen"};
          String v = Integer.toString(num);
          v = value[num];
      }
      public String toString(){
          String s = Card.setValue() + " of " + Card.setSuit();  
      }
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to set `suit` and `v` from within `toString()`.  Sounds like `toString()` should be: `return v + " of " + suit;`

Answer (score 0):

Your question and goal here is confusing/vague to me but I think this is what you're looking to do? If not, then you need to adjust the question and make it more clear. You should have a Card constructor that you pass the number to the Value and Suit instead of calling the methods statically with Card.setValue()/setSuit().

```java
public class Card {
   public Card(int value, int suit) {
      String theValue = setValue(value);
      String theSuit = setSuit(suit);

      if (theValue != null && theSuit != null)
         toString(theValue, theSuit);
      else
         System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
   }

   private String setSuit(int num) {
      String[] suits = {"clubs", "hearts", "diamonds", "spades"};
      if (num >= 0 && num < suits.length())
         return suits[num];
      else
         return null;
   }

   private String setValue(int num) {
      String[] value = {null, "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", 
         "King", "Queen"};
      if (num > 0 && num < value.length())
         return value[num];
      else
         return null;
   }

   private String toString(String value, String suit) {
      String s = value + " of " + suit;
      System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

and you can invoke this with:

```java
new Card(4, 2); //Prints 4 of diamonds
```